# Return Value Based On Item In Different Arrays - jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, if-statement

How would I determine what array an item is in jQuery? This is the code that I currently have:

```
var zips = ['30068', '90120','30033'];
var bad = ['314', '13567','1'];
$(function(){
  $('input[name=zip]').keyup(function(){
    var currentVal = $(this).val(); 
    if(!$.inArray(currentVal, zips)==-1){
     alert("if")
    } else if(!$.inArray(currentVal, bad)==-1){
     alert("else if")
    } else {
     alert("else")
      }
    });
});
```

What I want to happen is that when the user types in their zip code it decides what response to give. For example, if they type in *30033* then it would return **if**. If the user typed in *1* then it would return **else if** and if the user typed in anything else then it would return **else**. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `!$.inArray(currentVal, zips)==-1` if value not in array .. So you can use `$.inArray(currentVal, zips)> -1` instead

for me I think `.blur()` it will be better in this case .. so when you focusout the input you'll get the alert .. see the next example >>

```js
var zips = ['30068', '90120','30033'];
var bad = ['314', '13567','1'];
$(function(){
  $('input[name=zip]').on( 'blur' , function(){
    var currentVal = $(this).val(); 
    if($.inArray(currentVal, zips)> -1){
     alert("if")
    } else if($.inArray(currentVal, bad)> -1){
     alert("else if")
    } else {
     alert("else")
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="zip" />
```